# Group By .... Having SQL Query is not executing properly

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to see total product quantity sold within a date range i.e.

```
 -------------------------
 |  PRODUCT   | QUANTITY |
 -------------------------
 |   A        |    120   |
 -------------------------
 |   B        |     75   |
 -------------------------
```

I have the following sql query in **MS Access 2003**:

```
SELECT Product, Sum(PurchaseQuantity) AS Quantity
FROM tblInvoice
GROUP BY Product
HAVING PurchaseDate BETWEEN #3/19/2013# and #3/22/2013#;
```

But this is not executing. MS Access giving me error like:

> "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'PurchaseDate BETWEEN #3/19/2013# and #3/22/2013#' as part
>   of an aggregate function."

So far i understood that i need to add PurchaseDate in Group By clause. But is there any way to do it without putting PurchaseDate in Group By clause?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use purchaseDate condition in "WHERE" clause:

```
SELECT Product, Sum(PurchaseQuantity) AS Quantity 
FROM tblInvoice
WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN #3/19/2013# and #3/22/2013#
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: if i want to put Product, UnitName in SELECT clause but only Product in  GROUP BY clause ?